# In Minecraft plugin yml files like config.yml, how would I give something's nbt display a color?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-spigot

Like something like this:

```
   '1': '{"type":"DIAMOND"} {"type":"IRON_INGOT"} {"type":"DIAMOND"}'
   '2': '{"type":"DIAMOND"} {"type":"REDSTONE"} {"type":"DIAMOND"}'
   '3': '{"type":"AIR"} {"type":"AIR"} {"type":"AIR"}'
   craft: '{"type":"DIAMOND_PICKAXE","enchantments":[{"type":"LOOT_BONUS_BLOCKS","level":2},{"type":"PROTECTION_PROJECTILE","level":1},{"type":"PROTECTION_FIRE","level":1},{"type":"PROTECTION_EXPLOSIONS","level":1},{"type"}]}'
```

Answer (score 1):

**This is a plugin's yml file, meaning that how the information inside is handled depends entirely on the plugin's code. You should contact the plugin's author to ask if this is even possible, and if so, how it could be done.** However, following normal minecraft color name conventions, I would say you could try:

```
{"Name:"{\"text\":\"Foo\",\"color\":\"red\"}"}
```

Above is how minecraft itself does it with item NBT, but I highly doubt that this would work for your specific plugin's config.yml

Answer (score 1):

Most plugins do not support NBT. If you want to universally add colour, you need to use [Formatting Codes](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Formatting_codes). Many plugins replace the ampersand ("&"), with the section sign("§").

To change the item's name to red, simply set the item name in the config, and add `&c` to the beginning.

Unfortunately, this does not allow use of RGB colour.